# Using power cord without battery inserted in laptop

Tags: laptop, battery

Can I use the charger to power the computer without the battery? Will it damage the computer?

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/12358/is-it-better-to-use-a-laptop-on-battery-or-on-ac-power, http://superuser.com/questions/296667/using-a-toshiba-laptop-without-the-battery, http://superuser.com/questions/454179/using-a-laptop-without-battery

Answer (score 2):

Every laptop I have owned to retirement would work with the battery removed and/or with a completely exhausted battery installed. IMHO, most laptops are more ergonomic with the battery installed.

On an aside, it is best to avoid intentionally draining the battery. Li Ion batteries are good for about 300 charging cycles. So unless you need to use it off the cord, save those cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Some Acer (and maybe others) laptops with a faulty battery actually spend so much time checking if the battery is loading, that they slow down tremendously. Removing the battery and operating on the mains cable returns the laptop to normal speeds. The only risk you run is power failures.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your computer, but usually you can. And it can't damage the computer in any way.